# Networking code is not working properly, and is corrupting my data

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, http-proxy

So i am trying to write a simple proxy/relay to download a webpage trough. But it does not work very well. Sometimes the webpage is empty, or the images on the webpage are corrupted and incomplete, etc. So, it must be a networking problem. (the network stream is not completely read).
How can i solve this issue?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TrafficRerouter
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int bufferSize = 8196;
        private static string destIp = "www.projectrho.com";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartTcpListener(80);
        }
        private static byte[] SendReceiveRemoteServer(string host, int port, byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                var client = new TcpClient(host, port);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                var stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);

                Console.Write("\nSent to server: ");
                Col_Out(RemoveBinaryData(str), ConsoleColor.Red);

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                var bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
                var allBytes = new List<byte>();
                var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while (i != 0)
                {
                    allBytes.AddRange(bytes);

                    bytes = new Byte[bufferSize];
                    i = stream.DataAvailable ? stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) : 0;
                }
                str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);

                Console.WriteLine("\nReceived from server: ");
                Col_Out(RemoveBinaryData(str), ConsoleColor.DarkRed);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                return allBytes.ToArray();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            return new byte[0];
        }


        private static void StartTcpListener(int port)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    string s_received = "";
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    var stream = client.GetStream();

                    // Buffer for reading data

                    var bytes = new Byte[bufferSize];
                    var allBytes = new List<byte>();
                    var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while (i != 0)
                    {
                        allBytes.AddRange(bytes);

                        bytes = new Byte[bufferSize];
                        i = stream.DataAvailable ? stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) : 0;
                    }


                    if (allBytes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nReceived from client : ");
                        Col_Out(RemoveBinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes.ToArray())) + '\n', ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);


                        var received = SendReceiveRemoteServer(destIp, 80, allBytes.ToArray());
                        s_received = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(received);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(received, 0, received.Length);

                        Console.Write("\nSent to client : ");
                        Col_Out(RemoveBinaryData(s_received) + '\n', ConsoleColor.Green);
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            

            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        }

        private static char[] good_chars = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz/.,;:[]=+-_1234567890()*&\n\r".ToArray();
        static string RemoveBinaryData(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var c in s)
            {
                if (good_chars.Contains(c)) r.Append(c);
            }
            return (r.ToString() + "\n[BINARY_DATA]").Replace("\n", "█ ") + "\n";
        }
        static void Col_Out(string str, ConsoleColor c)
        {
            var oldc = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = c;
            Console.Write(str);
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldc;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is a "webpage trough"? Is "trough" a typo?

Comment: @AnnL. no. I want to route my traffic trough my program, kind of like a proxy server. So, i could basically download a website/file trough it, if it were to work. The issue is the networking code. It is corrupting my data.

Comment: I'm not trying to be unkind, but do you mean "through" rather than "trough"?  "Trough" is an English word, but it means something like "a ditch".

Comment: Wouldn't you normally need to download each image and file separately, if you want to download a web page and all the images, script, etc.?

Comment: Your "Loop to receive all the data sent by the client." is wrong, I think. If `stream.DataAvailable` is false then the loop will exit straight away, without waiting for more data to arrive. You should just be able to do `i = stream.Read(...);`

Comment: Are you sure that blindly decoding everything as UTF-16 is the right thing to do? Almost all of the web uses UTF-8

Comment: @canton7 the decoding does not matter. It is just for show and tell.

Comment: @AnnL. you are right!